# Subset ordinal domain for a bar chart

Tags: javascript, d3.js, dc.js

I have three categories to graph in a bar chart, hence, three bars. However, I would like to graph only two categories, two bars. I have categories A,B,C and I want to graph the subset A,B. Here is a working [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sbr2ovmk/4/). The problem is when I put `["A","B"]` into the `.x(d3.scale.ordinal().domain(["A","B"]))` the third bar is still graphed over one of the other ones. Help appreciated.

**HTML:**

```
<body> 
    <div id='bar1'><div><h3>Bar 1</h3></div></div>
</body>
```

**JS**

```
var data = [{
    Category: "A",
    ID: "1"
}, {
    Category: "A",
    ID: "1"
}, {
    Category: "A",
    ID: "1"
}, {
    Category: "A",
    ID: "2"
}, {
    Category: "A",
    ID: "2"
}, {
    Category: "B",
    ID: "1"
}, {
    Category: "B",
    ID: "1"
}, {
    Category: "B",
    ID: "1"
}, {
    Category: "B",
    ID: "2"
}, {
    Category: "B",
    ID: "3"
}, {
    Category: "B",
    ID: "3"
}, {
    Category: "B",
    ID: "3"
}, {
    Category: "B",
    ID: "4"
}, {
    Category: "C",
    ID: "1"
}, {
    Category: "C",
    ID: "2"
}, {
    Category: "C",
    ID: "3"
}, {
    Category: "C",
    ID: "4"
}, {
    Category: "C",
    ID: "4"
}, {
    Category: "C",
    ID: "5"
}];

var ndx = crossfilter(data);

var XDimension = ndx.dimension(function (d) {
    return d.Category;
});

dc.barChart("#bar1")
    .width(400).height(150)
    .dimension(XDimension)
    .group(XDimension.group().reduceSum(function(d){return d.ID}))
    .x(d3.scale.ordinal().domain(["A","B"]))
    .xUnits(dc.units.ordinal)

dc.renderAll();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a request for zooming or focus on ordinal charts here:

https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/issues/416

However, until that is implemented, I would suggest using the "fake group" technique described here:

https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/wiki/FAQ#how-do-i-filter-the-data-before-its-charted

A general filtering adapter might look like (untested):

```
function filtered_group(group, bins) {
  return {
    all:function () {
      return group.all().filter(function(d) {
        return bins.indexOf(d.key) != -1;
      });
    }
  }
};
```

Then use it like this:

```
var group0 = XDimension.group().reduceSum(function(d){return d.ID}),
    xgroup = filtered_group(group0, ["A", "B"]);
chart.group(xgroup);
```

Comment: Works beautifully. With your help I already figured out so many convenient workarounds. I am thinking of creating a manual with examples of all the questions I had.